# Star Button in Android

Tags: android, android-button

I'd like to put one star-shaped button in my app, just like a rating star.  I've already tried to use a one star rating bar, but unfortunately it doesn't work as a button.

I'd like it to work as a button, even better if the background of the selected state is yellow...any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure, use a layout resource like this:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:onClick="onToggleStar"/>
```

You can pair this with a state list drawable defined like this that is saved as an XML file at `res/drawable/star.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Here are the images that pack with Android itself:

- [image: Off]  Off
- [image: On]   On
- [image: Disabled]   Disabled
- [image: On Pressed]   On Pressed
- [image: Off Pressed]   Off Pressed

Comment: How can I get those images in a better resolution?

Comment: I got mine straight out of the <android sdk path>\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-hdpi folder.  The files start with the name "btn_star"

Comment: I get, cannot resolve drawable button_focused.. How can I fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: @jkschneider I tried your answer and it crashed when i click the button and logged `onToggleStar` view is not defined. So then i follwed @Mahyar Salamat's answer for adding view in java. But still it is crashing the app. Any solution to come up? i am using these in Fragment.

Answer (score 13):

You can just use the built-in `btn_star` statelist drawable.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favorite_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"  //This one! 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00ffffff" /> //Needed to remove the button background
```

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html for canonical list of drawables.

Comment: How do I make it yellow?

Comment: How can I check it programmatically ?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted my favorite button to behave like a checkbox, so this worked well for me, without having to add any image-toggling logic in my onClickListener. In my Java code I can use `myFavoriteToggleButton.isChecked()` to determine the action taken.

```
    <CheckBox
    android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/favorite"

    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: The perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty good tutorial for creating a custom button, from start to finish.  You can even create your own star image, if you want to get really crafty, for each of the button states.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXXCFmfJMNw

Answer (score 2):

Just add below code in your Activity:

```
final ImageButton ButtonStar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.star);
    ButtonStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isEnable){
                ButtonStar.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off));
            }else{
                ButtonStar.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on));
            }
            isEnable = !isEnable;
        }
    });
```

note that: define boolean isEnable=false global.
this is my ImageButton xml code:

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `StateListDrawable` for `Button`? Try it, buddy :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there's no such built-in control for Android. You will need to use a `Button` (or an `ImageButton`), and set the background (or the image resource) to [a drawable with states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to insert it as a text view. It was the easiest way I found to do this.

In the layout xml I added it as a text view

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_star_fav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:onClick="onToggleStar"
    android:text="★"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Then in the code wrote a function like the following.

```
boolean isfavourite;


public void onToggleStar(View view){
    TextView favouriteStar = (TextView) view;
    if(!isfavourite){
        // if the star is not already selected and you select it
        isfavourite = true;
        favouriteStar.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD600"));
    }else{
        // if the star is already selected and you unselect it
        isfavourite = false;
        favouriteStar.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use a `selector` which is helpful for the state of a `Button` (or an `ImageButton`) . refer [this](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/)